# My game is not listed on profile's game tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Here is my problem. I have developed a game for Facebook but it is not appearing on profile of players like these two games on the image below [image]

If anyone knows what to do about this please respond.

Best regards

Comment: How much content is your app posting to those users' profiles? I don't think there's any deterministic way to have an app included there - is your app definitely in the Games category? Is it listed in app center?

Comment: Hello! Yes, my app is definitely in game category and is listed in app center with 50k+ monthly users. It is not posting content to users profiles only what users decide to post via postToFeed dialog. Maybe the problem is that i am not using open graph posting such as scores, achievements and other actions...